# Unable to see todo List or todo Task for someone else in Microsoft Teams using todo-task API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am testing with the `To-Do task` API ([Create todoTask - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) in Microsoft Graph Explorer.

I am able to create and see the list and task in MS Teams Planner using below requests for my own:

```
POST /me/todo/lists
POST /me/todo/lists/{todoTaskListId}/tasks
```

If I am trying to create list or task for someone else using below, I am getting response as `created - 201` that is all good till now.

But if look into that MS Teams account into which I created list/task, no list or task is present in the planner. What is the issue behind this?

NOTE: I am passing `id` down not `userPrincipalName`.

```
POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/todo/lists
POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/todo/lists/{todoTaskListId}/tasks
```

Answer (score 1):

Point 1:

The todo API is a api to access the office 365 todo list, it has nothing to do with the [MS Planner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) tasks.  The MS Planner user tasks can be found [/me/planner/tasks and /user/{id}/planner/tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).  The two are not related any way (other than being a "task" in nature).  i.e. a ToDo task is not any planner plan and a planner task can't be a ToDo task.

Point 2:
Like the planner API, the [ToDo tasks API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) only supports the delgated permision and only for the "current" user.  So only /users/{your userid}/todo/lists works...

Until MS add application permission support for the ToDo API will you be able to access another users ToDo list API.  The same is true for the Planner API.

If you need such feature you may like to add a request over at the [MS todo user voice page](https://todo.uservoice.com/).